# Sitecore 9.0.1 EXM Convert Nested Dynamic Objects into Readable Custom Tokens

Tags: exm

How to convert nested dynamic objects into readable data when building email custom tokens without using strongly type models?

Here's my data:

```
{
  "Id":"126",
  "Fruits":[{"Number":"111", "Name":"Apple"}, {"Number":"112", 
  "Name":"Orange"}],
  "Price":250,
  "EmailAddress":"test126@test.com"
}
```

and I'm using DeserializeObject

```
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(result);
```

then pass it to the method below:

```
    protected virtual Dictionary<string, object> BuildCustomTokens(dynamic data)
    {
        var customTokens = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if(data != null)
        {
            foreach (var dataField in data)
            {
              customTokens.Add($"form_{dataField.Key}", dataField.Value);      
            }
        }

        return customTokens;
    }
```

It is working, but for array of objects like **"Fruits"**, it is formatted as objects. Sample Email:
[image]

Comment: I'd argue this isn't directly an EXM or Sitecore question and more of a general .NET question on how to use dynamic objects.

Comment: @PeteNavarra this one is solved. And you're right, this is a .NET Question. What would i do to this question?